# Opengl nvoglv32.dll exception when doing long draws

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm using opengl to render fractals, which can result in very long draw calls (multiple seconds). If the draw call ends up being too long (a couple of seconds), i get this error:
Unhandled exception at 0x69A5E899 (nvoglv32.dll) in Mandelbulb.exe: Fatal program exit requested.
Presumably opengl assumes i'm stuck in an infinite loop and therefore aborts the program.

I've isolated the problem, as it goes away if i lower the quality. (in the example code, notice that the program runs just fine if maxiterations is set to something reasonable like 1000).
Is there any way to hint to opengl that it shouldn't abort?
Maybe using compute shaders instead will work?

Sample code for reproducing (very stupid example, not the focus): make an opengl project, draw two triangles that overlap to form a rectangle covering the entire screen. Then use this fragment shader to color it.
Vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

out vec4 pos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    pos = position;
};
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
in vec4 pos;
const int maxIterations = 8000000;
void main()
{
    vec2 npos = pos.xy;
    vec2 z=vec2(0.0,0.0);
    int i = maxIterations;
    for (; i > 0; i--)
    {
        float y2 = z.y * z.y;
        float x2 = z.x * z.x;
        if (x2 + y2 > 4) break;
        z.y = 2*z.x*z.y+npos.y;
        z.x = x2 - y2 + npos.x;
    }
    color = vec4(float(i)/float(maxIterations));
};
```

Edit:
Trying what @Scheff recommended worked. However, i sadly can't accept the comment as an answer

Comment: On Windows, this could be related to [Timeout Detection and Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/display/tdr-registry-keys). Once, we stumbled into this we fiddled with the registry keys described in the link (until we fixed the issue by making our rendering faster). ;-) `Mandelbulb.exe` let me assume you are on Windows too.

Comment: @Scheff: the `.dll` part of `nvoglv32.dll` gives it away, too. :)

Comment: Which are the initial values of `vec2 z`? How do you prevent overflows?